# Error on adding SSL ceritifcate - Using Terraform modules

Tags: terraform, amazon-elb

Sorry for my bad english.

Module: terraform-aws-elb   Version: 2.0
Link: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/

I  trying use this module, but when I add an ARN from SSL certificate, this message are showing to me:

```
terraform apply myplan 

module.elb_http.module.elb.aws_elb.this: Creating...
Error: Error creating ELB: ValidationError: Secure Listeners need to specify a SSLCertificateId
        status code: 400, request id: id-for-my-request1

  on .terraform/modules/elb_http/terraform-aws-modules-terraform-aws-elb-43e3e76/modules/elb/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_elb" "this":
   1: resource "aws_elb" "this" {
```

For test, I changing this file:

```
.terraform/modules/elb_http/terraform-aws-modules-terraform-aws-elb-43e3e76/modules/elb/main.tf
```

And, changing the **ssl_certificate_id** parameter, of **lookup(listener.value, "ssl_certificate_id", null)** to my ARN from my Certificate, the ACM module and ELB work normally.

If anyone has been through this, thank you if you can help, if it is bad configuration on my part, I apologize.

---

### Environment configs

- Terraform Version: Terraform v0.12.18
- provider.aws v2.43.0
- ACM module version: 2.0
- ELB_HTTP module version: 2.0
- OS: Ubuntu 19.04

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    region = var.aws_region
}

module "acm" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/acm/aws"
  version = "~> v2.0"

validate_certificate  = false

  domain_name  = "domain.name.example"
  zone_id      = "zone-id"

  subject_alternative_names = [
    "*.example.domain.name",
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "example.domain.name"
  }
}


module "elb_http" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/elb/aws"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  name = var.name

  subnets         = var.lb_subnets
  security_groups = var.sgs
  internal        = false

  listener = [
    {
      instance_port     = var.instance_port
      instance_protocol = var.instance_protocol
      lb_port           = var.lb_port
      lb_protocol       = var.lb_protocol
    },
    {
      instance_port     = var.instance_port
      instance_protocol = var.instance_protocol
      lb_port           = var.lb_port
      lb_protocol       = var.lb_protocol
      ssl_certificate_id  = "ssl_ARN"

    },
  ]

  health_check = {
    target              = "HTTP:80/"
    interval            = 30
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 5
  }


  // ELB attachments
  number_of_instances = var.instaces_number
  instances           = var.instances_id

  tags = {
    Owner       = var.owner
    Environment = var.tag
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "aws_region" {
  description = "AWS Region"
}

variable "name" {
  description = "Cluster Name"
}
variable "lb_subnets" {
  description = "Cluster subnets"
  type  = list(string)
}

variable "sgs" {
  description = "Security Groups"
  type  = list(string)
}

variable "instance_port" {
  description = "Instance port"
  type  = number
}
variable "instance_protocol" {
  description = "Instance protocol"
  type  = string
}
variable "lb_port" {
  description = "LB port"
  type  = number
}
variable "lb_protocol" {
  description = "LB protocol"
  type  = string
}
variable "instaces_number" {
  description = "instances numbers"
  type  = number
}
variable "instances_id" {
  description = "Instance IDs"
  type  = list(string)
}

variable "owner" {
  description = "lb owner"
  type  = string
}
variable "tag" {
  description = "lb tag"
  type  = string
}
```

Regards!

Comment: can you post that line you modified

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Terraform code, ideally in a [mcve] that reproduces your error?

Comment: Sorry!!

In the module I have altered line #21.

I'm edit the post and add config example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.tf` I have these lines:

```
listener = [
  {
    instance_port     = var.instance_port
    instance_protocol = var.instance_protocol
    lb_port           = var.lb_port
    lb_protocol       = var.lb_protocol
  },
  {
    instance_port     = var.instance_port
    instance_protocol = var.instance_protocol
    lb_port           = var.lb_port
    lb_protocol       = var.lb_protocol
    ssl_certificate_id  = "ssl_ARN"
},
```

But, I did not need to declare values two times. I changed for:

```
listener = [
  {
    instance_port     = var.instance_port
    instance_protocol = var.instance_protocol
    lb_port           = var.lb_port
    lb_protocol       = var.lb_protocol
  },
```